# Change frame rate of png encoded video without changing number of frames?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, fps, framerate

I have the following video

```
Input #0, avi, from 'input.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:12.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 335548 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, pal8, 2048x2048, 338250 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : FileAVI write
```

It has 125 frames @ 10 fps. Now I am compressing it using

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec png  -compression_level 4  -vtag 'PNG ' output.avi
```

which results in a video like this:

```
Input #0, avi, from 'output.avi':
  Metadata:
    software        : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:12.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 36894 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: png (PNG  / 0x20474E50), pal8(pc), 2048x2048, 37185 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : FileAVI write
```

But the original file (a `.cxd` file) is 25fps, so I would like the final avi to be 25 fps, without dropping or adding frames.

I do not manage it. I have seen several suggestions but noe of them work or I can't follow them.

How can I change the ffmpeg command, so that output.avi is again lossless 125 frames @ 25fps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the setpts filter to retime frames.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec png  -vf "setpts=N/25/TB" -r 25 -compression_level 4  -vtag 'PNG ' output.avi
```

Comment: Perfect. Works nicely, even with non-integer fps.